# Sequelize range Timeline.create

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Where does `Timeline.create` come from [in the manual](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/?highlight=dates#range-types)?

```
// empty range:
Timeline.create({ range: [] }); // range = 'empty'

// Unbounded range:
Timeline.create({ range: [null, null] }); // range = '[,)'
// range = '[,"2016-01-01 00:00:00+00:00")'
Timeline.create({ range: [null, new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1))] });

// Infinite range:
// range = '[-infinity,"2016-01-01 00:00:00+00:00")'
Timeline.create({ range: [-Infinity, new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1))] });
```

I fail to find anything on `Timeline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an example model name. It would be defined something like this:

```
var Timeline = sequelize.define('Timeline', {
  range: Sequelize.RANGE(Sequelize.DATE),
  // [... some other columns here]
});
```

You can then create instances and pass two values (lower, upper) for that `range` column:

```
Timeline.create({
  range: [
    new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1)), // lower
    new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 1, 1))  // upper
  ]
});
```

(`create()` is a standard method of sequelize models. It creates an in-memory instance of a class - `Timeline` in this case, but it could be `Person`, `Car`, `Octopus` or anything else - and then saves it to the database table that model represents.)

Comment: So it is just a random model. Thanks, this makes sense. The way they show the values of range strings made me think that it could be a helper method to generate them.